# How would Humans React to New Continents Replacing Old Ones?

Tags: post-apocalypse

Dag nab it, the North Koreans have done it again! This time, they've created a massive ritual intended to replace the USA with a Communist North America to help Communism take over the world.

However, it didn't work how they wanted it to. Instead of destroying the USA, it replaced Australia, Papua New Guinea, New Zealand, and all of Oceania except Hawaii, with a massive continent. Where everything else went is not this answer's concern.

The new continent, called Hanei'ark, has every animal species that was killed off by humans (Dodos, Moa, Stellar Sea Cows, Quaggas, etc., etc.), and new plants, plus all sorts of fantasy species (Think D&D). Hanei'ark also has all of the land area of all of the stuff it replaced, plus about an additional full version.

The world simply changes natural phenomenon to help everything be as normal as possible. However, human brains are not changed.

***How would the non-governing population of humans  react to a new continent, complete with extinct creatures, new ones, fantasy creatures, new plant life, and new sapient species?***

Comment: There are currently 7 billions of humans. Each of them with their own mind. How do you expect us to summarize how they would react? You are basically asking for everybody's opinion. Please narrow down the question to something manageable and not opinion based.

Comment: Questions of type "How would X react to ..." tend to get closed as opinion-based.

Comment: Anybody who HAS that kind of power need not care what anybody else thinks. Anybody who USES that kind of power (obviously) does not care what anybody else thinks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Just do the same they do to america**

Historically they "discovered" America and invaded it and included it into the culture they already had.

So i guess there will be all the countries that will go to explore to colonize it. Human have enough weapon to handle approx every animal threat. Even if it takes many years.

Sapient species will be the biggest deal but it could be the same story as in the America story. Human can bring technology and start to make examination of every inch square of the new land.

But few years later the countries will have enough data to start living there and now know what this land is made of so you can easily imagine a war between many countries that want a piece of the big cake and that want to use and make profit from all the resources existing (maybe petrol, gold, precious stones, etc)
This place could be the land to the 3rd world war.

The sapient species should have to choose a side to survive.

For the main part of discovering the new land you should refer to the "discovery of America" and think about how it could happens today. Mystical creature can be put appart cause they are not mystical for the native (think about the turkey in america). And if the native are evolved enough maybe think about the Israel-Palestinian conflict to see how people could react if you force them to share their land